# Problemas para habilitar acesso remoto SQL Server + Android

Tags: android, sql, asp

Boa tarde
Fiz um webservice em asp.net, e preciso acessar ele por meio de uma aplicação android. Em qualquer função normal, ele funciona normalmente, mas se for alguma função que tenha acesso ao banco de dados, ocasiona o seguinte erro:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

Após algumas pesquisas, vi que tinha que habilitar uma opção no SQL Server Management, fazendo com que o acesso remoto fique habilitado, porém, eu uso o banco local do Visual Studio e não o próprio SQL Server. Como proceder?

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro vc tem que ver se tem algum firewall bloqueando o SQL Server (no seu computador ou no servidor). Porta 1433 é a padrão.

Depois vc tem que ir nas configurações do SQL Server e setar essa opção. Aqui tem um bom tutorial: http://blog.citrix24.com/configure-sql-express-to-accept-remote-connections/

Comment: De todo jeito, vou ter que instalar o SQL Server Management e o SQL Server Configuration Manager. Pensei que tivesse um jeito de habilitar isso pelo LocalDB, mas acho que não é possível. Obrigado